# PHP code for sending a post to my own wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

The scenario is the following :

- I am logged in on Facebook
- I have my own web page with an input box and a submit button
- When I click the submit button I want the content of the input box to be posted on my OWN wall.

I don't want to create an App on facebook to do this.
My goal is , that any user who uses my web page and is currently logged in on Facebook with his own credentials , to be able to post to his own wall.

I really appreciate any help or guidance (steps) in achieving this functionality.

Comment: Sounds like placing a link to facebook should enable all your users to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this, because then facebook users would end up with a lot of spam on their wall if any website could post to the wall of the visitor that visits the site.

What you should look at is this
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/17/posting-to-facebook-from-website-with-facebook-connect/

There you will find the code you need to use, with explanation on what to do, and why it has to be like this.

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: But I'm talking about only the current user and only if he is already linked in.
It is the same thing as if he decided to go to his own facebook wall and write something on it.
I want to achieve the same...only do it programmatically

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but for it to work you have to use the way I posted. You are talking about only the current user, yes, but that current user would be another user for another person viewing the site, and their wall. Facebook wont let websites automagicaly post on users wall like this. Because of security it _has_ to go through their API (Facebook connect)

Comment: So , my answer to the question "can I send posts to my own wall , without first creating an App inside FB and using its API" is NO ?

Comment: Yes, the answer is NO ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect  your user to Facebook (or open a new window) in order to offer them to share wall post.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>
```

There's no way to post just a message/status without them approving your application/without application

Comment: WOW !
That "would" be really great...but there isn't (?) a way to provide my own message as a parameter.
Also , as statet in FB documentation :
<<The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and will no longer be supported.
Please use the Like button whenever possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.>>

But how can the LIKE method substitute a post on a wall ???